# WPF Set DataTemplate Grid size in code behind (ResourceDictionary)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I have ResourceDictionary that holds Dialog template. It has own `DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DialogViewModel}"`. I would like to set this dialog "window" size on initialization. I know how to do it if I will add for example Height property to `DialogViewModel`. However this is not the right place to specify Height. How to do it in code behind and then Bind to that property? I think I have tried all the possible solutions I was able to find.

Basically I need to specify Height in `SplitDialog.xaml.cs`, let's say `Height=500` and then add it to `<Grid Margin="20,20,20,10" Tag="Category dialog" MinHeight="450" Height="???" x:Name="MainGrid">`, but how?

I have tried to add to `SplitDialog.xaml.cs` (returns Height is null):

```
  Grid gGrid = (Grid)this.FindName("MainGrid");

  gGrid.Height = 600;
```

SplitDialog.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="Controls.Styles.Dialog.SplitDialog"
                    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModels.Category;assembly=ViewModels">

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DialogViewModel}">

    <DataTemplate.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="20,20,20,10" Tag="Category dialog" MinHeight="450" x:Name="MainGrid">

    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

SplitDialog.xaml.cs:

```
  public partial class SplitDialog : ResourceDictionary
  {
    public SplitDialog()
    {

    }
  }
```

Comment: When do you want to set the `Height`? Either set in the template or wait until the template has been applied to an element and set it on the element.

Comment: @mm8 I want to set it on initialization. This is because there is a need to set height on initialization and MinHeight in template itself and allow user to resize => make it bigger if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide this logic in Loaded event of the Grid, e.g:

```
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">...
```

then in code-behind:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    if (grid != null)
    {
        grid.Height = 600;
    }
}
```

no?